# Retrieving the deleted DATA

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

How to retrieve the data that was deleted accidentally? I know that we can retrieve the truncated data if that session was not closed(just by simple rollback). As, delete is a logged operation, is the restoring the database is the only option to retrieve the lost data?

Comment: Restoring database to the latest backup is your only option.

Comment: Take your latest backup and restore it to a ***different*** server. Now you can select the deleted data and insert it into the main server.

Comment: What recovery mode in your database in?

Comment: Yeah, I am asking a generic ques bridge. I know that if it is in full, I can get point in time recovery and we cant in bulk and simple. Anyway thanks for the response guys